# Input data in german data format combined with ChartsJs

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, chart.js

I'm relative new to Charts.js, but I'll need it to create some nice graphs for my webpage. In the background I have a Django project running which computes me a certain amount of numbers. Since I've put the language code in Django to "de-at" (requirement, since there are some input variables to fill in by austrian users), the number formats are done like: "1.000.000,54€" and not the US-way like "1,000,000.54€".

If I now want to add some of my data into charts.js, it won't read the data, which has more than 6 digits. Furthermore, if there is a number like "653.598,36" it takes actually two parameters, namely (653,598 ; 36).

Formatting the numbers in python does not help, since charts.js won't use strings for the graphs. Using the setting "locale = 'de-DE'" in the charts.js options only helps for labelling propertes, not for the data itself.

If I change the Django setting back to "en-us", charts.js works with the numbers, but than my numbers on the webpage are not formatted correctly for the end-user.

Has someone experienced this problem and has a solution to it?

Thank you and best regards!

Here is the code of charts.js with example values. I used chart.js directly in a HTML-file.

Note: The numbers in the data-section are just examples. Usually, there is a variable in it, which has the value.

```html
<canvas id="testChart" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.min.js"></script>
                <script>
                var ctx = document.getElementById('testChart').getContext('2d');
                var testChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                    type: 'bar',
                    data: {
                        labels: ['+', '-'],
                        datasets: [{
                            label: 'Years 1 - 20',
                            data:  [ 568.987,68, 0],
                            backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }, {
                            label: 'Einnahmen nach 20',
                            data:  [ 1.265.986,32 , 0],
                            backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        },{
                            label: 'EK',
                            data:  [0, 120.000,00],
                            backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(200, 50, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                            'rgba(200, 50, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }, {
                            label: 'FK',
                            data:  [0, 480.000,00],
                            backgroundColor: [
                            'rgba(150, 20, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderColor: [
                            'rgba(150, 20, 132, 0.2)'
                            ],
                            borderWidth: 1
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        plugins: {
                            title: {
                                display: true,
                                text: 'Testgrafik'
                            },
                        },
                        locale: 'de-DE',
                        responsive: true,
                        scales: {
                            x: {
                                stacked: true,
                            },
                            y: {
                                stacked: true
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting the numbers in that library, do this:
EDIT2: I misread your question, I thought you were asking how to change the floating point integers formats.

```
let n = "653.598,36";
let result = "";
let decimalPart = n.split(",")[1];
let decimalPartLen = decimalPart.length;
n = n.replace(".",""); //parseFloat doesn't like commas
let commaIndex = n.length - decimalPartLen;
result = parseFloat(n.substr(0,commaIndex - 1)+"."+n.substr(commaIndex, n.length));
console.log(result);
```

EDIT: this is client side js, but you could do this in python with minimal changes
Here it is in python:

```
n = "653.598,36"
result = ""
decimalPart = n.split(",")[1]
decimalPartLen = len(decimalPart)
n = n.replace(".","")
commaIndex = len(n) - decimalPartLen
result = float(n[:commaIndex-1]+"."+n[commaIndex:])
print(result)
```